Big speed difference for the same query executed on 2 different Oracle schemas
I have 2 different schemas installed on the same Oracle server (v12c).
On each of these 2 schemas, I have the same DB LINK which points to a distant database which allows me to read a table (size ±12,000 rows, a few basic columns (no blob)).
When I execute/compile in TOAD a SELECT * from TABLE@DBLINK on the first schema: 140ms
When I execute/compile in TOAD a SELECT * from TABLE@DBLINK on the second schema: 900ms
I've compared the two schemas quickly, and they seem identical (same tablespaces, same grants, etc.).
What could explain this slowness?
Should I compare the differences between these schemas in depth with a tool, if that makes sense?
Execution plan schema 1

Execution plan schema 2


Look at the execution plans for both schemas to see what the optimiser is choosing to do differently. (I think Toad might have its own tool to gather and display stats?) Maybe start by checking the statistics are up to date in both schemas - I'm guessing you've cloned one schema to create the other, and stats are stale.

@AlexPoole, I have added the execution plans and they are differents. I don't know why. I am sorry I am not DBA, is there an easy path to check/reset stats?

Apparently your "table" isn't a table, but a view that joins multiple tables on the remote database. And, you aren't simply querying the table by itself, but joining it to a local table (COUNTRY). Those differences matter.
In one case Oracle is merging the view and using the local database as the driving site, requiring it to pull all the pieces together locally and perform the joins there. In the other scenario, it is not merging the view and executing it entirely on the remote.
Try adding these hints (match the alias to the table alias, which you will want to add):
SELECT /*+ driving_site(x) no_merge(x) */ * from VIEW@DBLINK x

As to why it is different in one schema than another: there are many potential factors that might change it. The local table COUNTRY may be a different size in one schema than the other, or have different statistics, or be missing statistics in one. Your links may be pointed to two different databases even if the link name is the same; they may be using two different connect accounts which could be resolving to different objects on the remote. etc. It's enough to know that the smallest differences can result in considerably different plans; variability of plan like that is quite common.

I understand, but the definition of the views is identical on both schemas. Why would one merge on country and the other not?

@b126, See my last paragraph. This is very typical of Oracle. You can't expect the same plan every time in every situation. There are too many variables that go into the optimizer's work.

thank you for your precise explanations! In the meantime, I've noticed a mistake in one of the two views : I was using two DBLINKS pointing to the same target but with different names. By renaming the faulty DBLINK in the view, everything went back to normal. But I think this proves that you're right, Oracle can choose one solution or the other
